# How might I change the destination of a link?

Tags: custom-post-types, content

I am new to WordPress.  I have a 'News' content (Pages > Venue) and want to change the link's destination.  I have tried replacing the URL via JS, but it reads the script's innerHTML as regular text.  I have also tried child themes, but I have failed to implement them.  Things that articles have talked about just aren't there.  I have been working for an hour on this with no luck, is that too little?

Link to the site: http://www.opecconference.com/venue/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could create a custom link in the menu (Appearance > Menu > Custom Links). If it is something else, you might find [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/) helpful.